# divide each column value with its first value in a matrix

Tags: r, shell

I have a matrix like following:

```
totalreadcount  36  27  13  13
bna-miR172e-3p  0   1   4805    2767
bna-miR167a 4   26  11818   15776
bna-miR172a 0   0   4302    2464
bna-miR319b-3p  102 60  94  51
bna-miR156a 0   0   139 59
bna-miR167d 38  108 55389   58479
```

I would like to divide each value of column by its first value.for example: in second column 36 is first value and i need to divide rest values like 0,4,102,0,38 by 36 and same with the other columns.
the matrix size is big, so anybody help me in doing such calculation through shell script  or R-language scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1 && NF>1 {$1=$1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i}
     NR>1{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i=$i/a[i]} 1' file

totalreadcount 36 27 13 13
bna-miR172e-3p 0 0.037037 369.615 212.846
bna-miR167a 0.111111 0.962963 909.077 1213.54
bna-miR172a 0 0 330.923 189.538
bna-miR319b-3p 2.83333 2.22222 7.23077 3.92308
bna-miR156a 0 0 10.6923 4.53846
bna-miR167d 1.05556 4 4260.69 4498.38
```

**Explanation:**

In the first block I have:

```
NR==1 && NF>1 {$1=$1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i}
```

Which runs only for 1st record of the file and stores each columns from #2 onwards value in an array `a`. `$1=$1` is simple trick to change excess white spacing of the record.

In the 2nd block I have:

```
NR>1{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i=$i/a[i]}
```

Here for each column from #2 onwards we are dividing column value by corresponding array value stored in `a`. Finally `1` is used for printing the values on stdout.

Comment: its working, please explain me its working methodology

Comment: Adding explanation to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
> mat <- matrix(1:15, 5, 3)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15
> mat[-1, ] / mat[1, ] # divide all rows except the first one by the first row
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 2.0000000 1.1666667  1.090909
[2,] 0.5000000 0.7272727 13.000000
[3,] 0.3636364 9.0000000  2.333333
[4,] 5.0000000 1.6666667  1.363636
```